# Изменить фон тега select в зависимости от выбраного варианта?

Tags: html, css

Можно ли средствами `CSS` стилизировать `select`  в зависимости от выбраного варианта?

```html
<select class="select" name="colors">
  <option value="red">Red</option>
  <option value="green">green</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Только чистым CSS-ом никак, можно с небольшим куском JS:

```html
<select class="select" name="colors" onchange="this.style.backgroundColor=this.options[this.selectedIndex].style.backgroundColor"> 
    <option style="background-color:red" value="red">Red</option> 
    <option style="background-color:green" value="green">Green</option>
</select>
```

Comment: А можно добавить фон только для выбраного результата без выпадающего списка?(Не `option`, а `select` где отображается результат )

Comment: @E_K измените цвет для `option` на белый, а в обработчике замените в конце `style.backgroundColor` на `value`.